# Auto update time by 2 minutes till window closed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a module where I am storing date and time(in_time and out_time) in a database table for a web page. What I actually want is to keep adding 2 minutes to the out_time column after every two minutes till the web page is closed or by any means if a user moves away from the page. I have implemented the following code to the problem but didn't get any success.

This is written on my page about which I want to make record,

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    function out_ajax(){
    $.ajax({ 
      type:"POST",
      url:"out_time.php",
      success:function(html){
       }   
        });
    }

    window.setInterval(function(){
        out_ajax();
    }, 120000);
});
    </script>
```

And my out_time.php looks as,

```
<?php
@session_start();

         $dbhost = 'localhost';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = '';
         $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }
         echo '';
         mysql_select_db( 'dbname' );

$uid        =   $_SESSION['session_user_id'];
$moduleId       =   $_REQUEST['module_id'];
$chapterId      =   $_REQUEST['chapter_id'];
$time_taken     =   $_REQUEST['seconds'];
$created        =   date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$last_id =  $_SESSION["last_id"];

$update_time = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_ppt_time SET out_time = now() WHERE id='$last_id'  AND user_id = '$uid' AND module_id='$moduleId' AND chapter_id='$chapterId'");

?>
```

Comment: You have to use `AJAX` for this

Comment: Thanks for the time and concern but can you please guide on how to do this. new to web development part and least knowing about AJAX. Thanks in  advance

Comment: You have to search and develop code. If you stuck over there you can ask here for help. But nobody will teach you On SO everything

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: But may I know how to do this. Although AJAX has to be used but what should be the roadmap for this. i am bit confused over this. @B.Desai

Comment: First make a php file which update time by 2 minutes, then call this php file through ajax. Set a timeout function in your js which run ajax after every 2 minute. that's the roadmap.

Comment: @SaadSuri Thank you for lightning me  up. I have implemented as you directed, but somewhere something is missing as it doesn't shows desired result. I have edited my question, If possible, kindly take a look.

Comment: @B.Desai I have done the way you said, I have edited my question, if possible please take a look.